# .htaccess - serve requests on a .phar file if found, otherwise serve on index.php

Tags: .htaccess, phar

I want to deploy a web application packaged in a .phar file and serve requests from it like I actually do from an index.php file in `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`.

The default `mod_rewrite` in Apache goes like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I wanted to do the same with a .phar file I suppose (although I may be wrong, so any direction would be more than welcome) I could do it like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /application.phar [L]
</IfModule>
```

I could always have two .htaccess files and use the appropiate one depending on the type of deployment but I would like to support BOTH strategies if possible. Whether I want to run an application packaged or unpackaged, I want to be able to re-use the .htaccess file between projects but taking into account the packaged version should be the preferred way.

How can I combine these two different rules in just one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # ignore all existing files/directories from rewrite
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # if application.phar exists then use it
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application.phar -f
    RewriteRule ^ application.phar [L]

    # otherwise use index.php
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I still lack some testing for the .phar file but the .htaccess rules are working like a charm :)